# ionic not redirecting in inappbrowser

Tags: javascript, angularjs, ionic-framework

hi all i am using ionic working with inappbrowser from controller $window but i am not able to achieve help how to solve here i attached my code

## controller

```
 var options = {
      location: 'yes',
      clearcache: 'yes',
      toolbar: 'no'
    }

    //url redirect code
    $scope.urlredirect = function (url) {
      alert(url)
      $window.open(url, '_blank', options);
```

## html

```
 <div class="card"  ng-click=urlredirect('https://www.google.co.in/?gfe_rd=cr&ei=-K-iWb3mO-HH8gfMkpQo') >
            <div class="item item-text-wrap" >

            </div>
        </div>
```

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Try switch `$window` to `window`:

```
window.open(url, '_blank', 'location=yes');
```

Answer (score 0):

why not you use Cordova plugin for inapp browser? It have multiple configurable options many of your problems will got resolved in theemable browser plugin 
Plugin link : [here](https://www.npmjs.com/package/cordova-plugin-themeablebrowser)

```
cordova.ThemeableBrowser.open('http://apache.org', '_blank', { ... backButton: { wwwImage: 'images/back.png', wwwImagePressed: 'images/back_pressed.png', wwwImageDensity: 2, align: 'left', event: 'backPressed' } ... });
```